# Convert spark dataframe to list of tuples without pandas dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have an existing logic which converts pandas dataframe to list of tuples.

```py
list(zip(*[df[c].values.tolist() for c in df]))
```

where df is a pandas dataframe.

Somebody please help me implement the same logic without pandas in pyspark.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what the relation between pandas and spark is and why you're mentioning it.

Comment: df is created by calling toPandas() on a spark dataframe, I would like directly convert the spark dataframe to list of tuples.

Answer (score 5):

You can first convert the `dataframe` to an `RDD` using the `rdd` method.
A [`Row`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html#Row) in dataframes is a `tuple` too, so you can just:

```
rdd = df.rdd
b = rdd.map(tuple)
b.collect()
```

Example DF:

```
df.show()
+-----+-----+
| Name|Score|
+-----+-----+
|name1|11.23|
|name2|14.57|
|name3| 2.21|
|name4| 8.76|
|name5|18.71|
+-----+-----+
```

After `b.collect()`

```
[('name1', 11.23), ('name2', 14.57), ('name3', 2.21), ('name4', 8.76), ('name5', 18.71)]
```

### EDIT

If you're going to loop over this list of tuples, You may call `collect()` but the right method is [`toLocalIterator()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.toLocalIterator)

Comment: I liked your solution, can we do it without collect?

Comment: @Thomas collect has been just used to show you output. The solution works witbout collect

Comment: I have another method which is expecting list of tuples and doesn't work if i pass b to it since b is still a rdd

Comment: @Thomas I extended my answer

Answer (score 2):

An alternative without `collect` but with `collect_list`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.show()
+-----+-----+
| Name|Score|
+-----+-----+
|name1|11.23|
|name2|14.57|
|name3| 2.21|
|name4| 8.76|
|name5|18.71|
+-----+-----+

@F.udf
def combo(*args):
  return [_ for _ in args][0]

df.withColumn('Combo', combo(F.array('Name','Score'))).agg(F.collect_list('Combo')).show(truncate=False)

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|collect_list(Combo)                                                       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[name1, 11.23],[name2, 14.57],[name3, 2.21],[name4, 8.76],[name5, 18.71]]|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```